# Changes in ASP.NET from version 2.0 to 4.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wish to learn ASP.NET and found some good videos about it. But the thing is that they are for version 2.0 of the .Net Framework. Has ASP.NET changed drastically from version 2.0 till 4.0?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562 - You should do some research about it. a simple search resulted http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868.aspx

Comment: @DennisTraub you're right... updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you should focus your effort on 4.0.  
 When 2.0 was released Ajax started to go mainstream due the wow factor of google maps, data binding was without Entity Framework or Linq and deployment was more copy and paste.  All the tutorials you need can be found on here: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse there will be new features added in the newer versions. But the 4.0 version supports all(i guess, or most of the stuff) the features available in the previous versions. So learning 2.0 version will not harm you. Once you get a basic undestanding of the ASP.NET( which you can easily get by stydying 2.0), you can look into the new features introduced in the newer versions.

Comment: So, learn it the wrong way first, and then later learn it the correct way? :)

Comment: 2.0 is not the wrong way ! the basics are same for 2.0 and 4.0. As a beginner, learning 2.0 would give you the basic understanding of how it works

Comment: You are of course right. I was just kidding. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

- Here's a documentation of the [ASP.NET 4 breaking changes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes)
- Also take into consideration that there have been some changes to the [validation mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132368/can-i-deploy-net-4-0-web-application-on-iis6/3132724#3132724)

Comment: ok, it seems there have been lots of changes. Maybe I should just try to learn ASP.Net 4.0 right from the start. Thanks for the link :)