# Window server 2003 IIS 6 and asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I´m working on asp.net mvc 4 project with entity framework 5 and visual studio 2012, but now my client tell me that he has window server 2003 with internet information server 6. I never deploy an mvc 4 project in IIS 6. I want to know what I have to do for run this project, or I have to start another project, like mvc1 or 2 (Hope not). What are my options ???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I deploy .net 4.0 web application on IIS6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132368/can-i-deploy-net-4-0-web-application-on-iis6)

Comment: Other than performing proper requirements gathering up front?  Try out some of these tutorials: http://blog.binarymist.net/2011/10/24/getting-mvc-4-running-on-server-2003/
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/

Comment: JMK yes I read it, but they are talking about net 3.5. My case is 4.5. Maybe there is not big difference betwen these two when is about deployment, but I just want to be sure that it's possible to do this, because I never work with IIS6.

Comment: I'm in the same situation - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136191/how-can-i-deploy-an-mvc-4-application-to-iis-6

Answer (score 0):

This was passed on to me by Vijai Singh and was very helpful - [blogpost from Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are things you can do to get an MVC4 project up and running on IIS6 (theoretically), however you cannot get .NET framework 4.5 running on Windows Server 2003.  So, if you're going to try this, make sure you're using framework 4.